# How to cut a dynamic string

Tags: android

I have a string like this `one two three four`. I want to cut this string and make four strings like `one`, `two`, `three` and `four`. How can I do this?

The string is a dynamic string. The four words of this string change, therefor I want to do something appropriate for any string length.

Comment: string.split(), really should google search before you ask a q.

Comment: I suggest reading [Asking the Perfect Question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) before asking again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] strings;
String str = "one two three";
String delimiter = " ";
strings = str.split(delimiter);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] strings = "one two three".split("\\B");
```

Answer (score 1):

String has a split method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

You pass it a regex that represents your delimiter. For your example you'd do this:

```
String[] ar = string.split(" ");
```